# Getting items from Firebase duplicates when using a custom sign in

Tags: java, android, firebase, debugging, duplicates

So I've been working on my own audio recording app that uses Firebase for account sync and off device storage of recordings. I initially used FirebaseUI for sign in, but I wanted to switch to my own custom sign in page and just using the signInWithEmailPassword() Firebase method. But after I made the switch, I noticed that upon the sign in and loading of the recording items onto my RecyclerView, items are duplicated for some reason. However, doing anything with the application would revert it back to the original number of items.

For my application, I use anonymous account conversion for signing up, so if you recorded anything as an anonymous user, it would be saved when you sign up foran account with your email. I call the same method to load the recordings every single time after you sign in or sign up, but it's only when you sign in does it duplicate. I'm super confused as to why it's duplicating.

So, I tried to debug this method because I printed out how many items show up in the list and it ends up being doubled. I checked the Firebase console and it's legit half of what's being inputted into the list, so I am not sure how I'm getting twice the amount of recordings from Firebase if it isn't duplicated on the console.

```
    public static void loadSavedRecordings(String uid, OnRetrieveListListener listener) {
        // set uid
        userId = uid;

        // Log the current amount of recordings
        Log.d("RECORDINGS BEFORE", listOfRecordings.size() + "");

        // Clear the list of recordings
        listOfRecordings.clear();

        // Gets the listener
        mListener = listener;

        // list the files out
        StorageReference listRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("audio/" + uid);

        // List all items from list
        listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {

                // Lists out the items
                for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {

                    // Creates the uri, time, and name variable for getting data on recording
                    final Uri[] mUri = new Uri[1];
                    final long[] time = new long[1];
                    final String[] name = new String[1];

                    // Creates a final reference
                    final StorageReference mReference = item;

                    // all items under the list
                    mReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            // Get absolute path to file
                            String absolutePath = uri.toString();

                            // get uri of the file
                            mUri[0] = uri;
                            Log.d("PATH", absolutePath);

                            // Get the date metadata
                            mReference.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {

                                    // Get metadata for the recording to display to user
                                    time[0] = storageMetadata.getCreationTimeMillis();
                                    String title = storageMetadata.getCustomMetadata(TITLE);
                                    String fileName = storageMetadata.getName();

                                    // Tells listener that metadata is finished being retrieved
                                    mListener.onListComplete("Complete");

                                    // Load the recording onto the application
                                    loadRecording(mUri[0], time[0], title, fileName);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e("FAIL TO DL", "Oh no, failed to download");
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e("List error", "Oh no, can't list items");
            }
        });

    }
```